# Get key from input id jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have list with several inputs

```
<input type="hidden" id="elevens_id_ea" value="<?php echo $_GET['elev_id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="arskursen_ea" value="<?php echo $arskursen; ?>" />

<?php
if ($extraanpassning_hamta['atgard'] == true){ 
    ?>
    <input name="extraanpassning" id="knapp[<?php echo $amnets_id['amne_id']; ?>]" type="button" class="btn-u rounded btn-u-red btn-sm" value="Ja">
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input name="extraanpassning" id="knapp[<?php echo $amnets_id['amne_id']; ?>]" type="button" class="btn-u rounded btn-u-green btn-sm" value="Nej">
<?php } ?>
```

The main problem is how to "catch" the value in the two latest inputs with:

```
id="knapp[<?php echo $amnets_id['amne_id']; ?>]"
```

If `knapp[4]` -> how do I get the 4?

The code above is a part of a button that changes value when the user presses it (without refreshing the page).

The JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    var extraanpassningVal = $(this).attr("value");
    var amne_id_ea = $(this).attr("id");
    var elevens_id_ea = $("#elevens_id_ea").val(); //värdet av elev_id   
    var arskursen_ea = $("#arskursen_ea").val(); //värdet av elev_id       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "iup_extraanpassning_byta.php",
        data: {extraanpassningType: extraanpassningVal, amne_id_ea: amne_id_ea, elevens_id_ea: elevens_id_ea, arskursen_ea: arskursen_ea},
        success:  function() {
        location.reload();
     }

  })
});
});
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

The main problem is how to get the key from a input with an id like knapp[4].

How do get the key within knapp[]?

**Update (thanks to *user:SpYk3HH*)**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    var key = this.id.replace(/knapp|\[|\]/g, ''),  //  <---They key
        extraanpassningVal = $(this).attr("value"),
        amne_id_ea = $(this).attr("id"),
        elevens_id_ea = $("#elevens_id_ea").val(),
        arskursen_ea = $("#arskursen_ea").val();
    if (this.ajax) this.ajax.abort(); //  helps prevent multiple ajaxing (multiclicking)
    this.ajax = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "iup_extraanpassning_byta.php",
            data: {extraanpassningType: extraanpassningVal, amne_id_ea: amne_id_ea, elevens_id_ea: elevens_id_ea, arskursen_ea: arskursen_ea},
            success:  function() {
            location.reload();
            }
        })
})
});
</script>
```

Comment: Catch the value for what? where? why? Your question needs a little more explanation.

Comment: Also, you can easily shorten that whole if statement to one line, like so: `<input name="extraanpassning" id="knapp[<?php echo $amnets_id['amne_id']; ?>]" type="button" class="btn-u rounded btn-u-<?php echo $extraanpassning_hamta['atgard'] == true ? 'red btn-sm" value="Ja"' : 'green btn-sm" value="Nej"'; ?> />`

Comment: I have updated my question (see above).  `var amne_id_ea = $(this).attr("id");` How do I catch the key from the input within the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it? You want the key when calling the button in JS? So like say: `key = this.id.replace(/knapp|\[|\]/g, '')`

> Update, I didn't see the brackets before

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    var key = this.id.replace(/knapp|\[|\]/g, ''),  //  <---They key
        extraanpassningVal = $(this).attr("value"),
        amne_id_ea = $(this).attr("id"),
        elevens_id_ea = $("#elevens_id_ea").val(),
        arskursen_ea = $("#arskursen_ea").val();
    if (this.ajx) this.ajx.abort(); //  helps prevent multiple ajaxing (multiclicking)
    this.ajx = $.ajax({/*   options */});
})
```

Does that help?

FYI, `$(this).attr("id")` and `this.id` are the same thing

```js
$('[name=test]').each(function(i) { $('#bob').text(this.id.replace(/knapp|\[|\]/g, '')) })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="knapp4" name="test" value='my id is "knapp[4]"' />
<hr />
key: <span id="bob"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var amne_id_ea = "knapp[4]",
    value = amne_id_ea.substring(amne_id_ea.lastIndexOf("[")+1,amne_id_ea.lastIndexOf("]"));
alert(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope you are expecting this.